# Upload Image Request from React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express

What I am trying to achieve is to send a request from the Client Side (React) to the Server Side (Express) containing the uploaded image file

Here an example of a form I created on the Server which sends the data I should be sending with React instead:

```
<form method="post" action="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image" /><br /><br />
  <button type="submit" name="upload">Upload</button>
</form>
```

This is the object sent by the submitted form when uploaded an image: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph9sp.png)

Here the React Component:

```
const Component = () => {
  const setImageAction = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/upload/post", {
      method: "post",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
      body: JSON.stringify({

      }),
    });
    const uploadedImage = await data.json();
    if (uploadedImage) {
      console.log('Successfully uploaded image');
    } else {
      console.log('Error Found');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="content">
      <form onSubmit={setImageAction}>
        <input type="file" name="image" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="submit" name="upload">
          Upload
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

As you can see, in the React Component the body request is empty as I haven't figured out how to retrieve that file object..

Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDIT**

Updated as shown, with the only difference of keeping State as Hook

Here the new React Component Code:

```
const LandingPage = () => {
  const [picture, setPicture] = useState({});

  const uploadPicture = (e) => {
    setPicture({
      /* contains the preview, if you want to show the picture to the user
           you can access it with this.state.currentPicture
       */
      picturePreview: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
      /* this contains the file we want to send */
      pictureAsFile: e.target.files[0],
    });
  };

  const setImageAction = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", picture.pictureAsFile);

    console.log(picture.pictureAsFile);

    for (var key of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(key[0] + ", " + key[1]);
    }

    const data = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/upload/post", {
      method: "post",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
      body: formData,
    });
    const uploadedImage = await data.json();
    if (uploadedImage) {
      console.log("Successfully uploaded image");
    } else {
      console.log("Error Found");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="content landing">
      <form onSubmit={setImageAction}>
        <input type="file" name="image" onChange={uploadPicture} />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="submit" name="upload">
          Upload
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here what I get from those console.logs: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xXrm.png)

I created a snippet in codesandbox if you want to have a look at: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-snyder-d67sn?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add this method to capture the onChange event :

add 2 properties to your state : picturePreview and pictureAsFile

```js
uploadPicture = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            /* contains the preview, if you want to show the picture to the user
               you can access it with this.state.currentPicture
           */
            picturePreview : URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
            /* this contains the file we want to send */
            pictureAsFile : e.target.files[0]
        })
    };
```

now, on your onSubmit event :

```js
setImageAction = () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append(
            "file",
            this.state.pictureAsFile
        );
        // do your post request

    };
```

of course don't to add the uploadPicture method to your input:

```js
 <input type="file" name="image" onChange={this.uploadPicture}/>
```

**EDIT**

to display your formData :

```js
for (var key of formData.entries()) 
{
    console.log(key[0] + ', ' + key[1])
}
```

Comment: I followed your example and I can now display the file uploaded accessing pictureAsFile; Only problem is the formData.append doesn't work. If I tried to display it I get an empty object; Any idea why?

Comment: well FormData is a special object, that cannot be displayed using console.log

Comment: also, its not stringifyable, so th body must contain directly your FormData

Comment: i've added a way to log your dataForm content

Comment: I've updated as you suggested; Please see codesandbox for details

Comment: can you show your server-side code? you're getting a 500 error code so maybe the issue is in express

Comment: Sorry for not replying, totally forgot. Anyway I found the problem keep looking on the net, and found to be the headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } that didn't have to be set when uploading files. By just removing that line of code I solved the issue. Your comment helped me a lot though.

Comment: No problem. Good luck